# Snap Install Bitcoin Core on WSL Ubuntu 22 doesn't add binaries to PATH

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu, windows, wsl

I'm trying to **install bitcoin-core on my WSL Ubuntu 22**. I've already snap-installed bitcoin core on my bare bone Ubuntu 22 and once completed it adds to the path the binaries `bitcoin-core.{cli,daemon}`, and everything works fine.

When Installing on WSL Ubuntu 22, I do `snap install bitcoin-core`, it says everything is fine, but the `bitcoin-core` binaries aren't added to my PATH. I've tried restarting my shell session, searching in `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin` and other known binary paths but I'm not able to find out the `bitcoin-core` binaries location. Any hint?

Comment: Please take a look at [what to do when someone answers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Did you look in /snap/bin/? That's the normal place snap installs to